# Google Visualization ChartWrapper set cell value programmatically

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

When I click on a line item a Google visualization `ChartWrapper` table, I want to programmatically update the product value in the row that was clicked.

I'm getting stuck here:  `dataTable.setValue(row, col, valNew);`

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_setValue) I should be able to use `setValue` to update a value in the datable.  I'm getting error "setValue is not a function".

Hoping that someone can point me in the right direction...

Here is my code so far.  The problem is in the `selectHandler_table_db` function.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['table', 'controls']
}).then(function() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Product');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');

  var dt1 = new Date(moment().endOf('month').subtract(3, 'month'));
  var dt2 = new Date(moment().endOf('month').subtract(2, 'month'));
  var dt3 = new Date(moment().endOf('month').subtract(1, 'month'));
  var dt4 = new Date(moment().startOf('month'));
  var dt5 = new Date(moment().startOf('month').add(1, 'day'));
  var dt6 = new Date(moment().startOf('month').add(2, 'day'));

  data.addRows([
    [dt1, 'a', 100],
    [dt2, 'b', 200],
    [dt3, 'a', 300],
    [dt4, 'b', 400],
    [dt5, 'a', 500],
    [dt6, 'b', 600],
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

  example_dashboard(view);

});

function example_dashboard(view) {

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('div_dashboard'));

  var categoryPicker1 = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'div_categoryPicker1',
    options: {
      filterColumnIndex: view.getColumnIndex('Product'),
      matchType: 'any',
      ui: {
        labelStacking: 'vertical',
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: false,
        allowNone: true
      }
    }
  });

  var table_db = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'div_table',
    options: {
      width: '100%',
      height: 'auto',
    }
  });

  dashboard.bind(categoryPicker1, table_db);
  dashboard.draw(view);

  google.visualization.events.addListener(table_db, 'select', selectHandler_table_db);

  function selectHandler_table_db() {

    let chartWrapper = table_db.getChart();
    let dataTable = table_db.getDataTable();
    let row = chartWrapper.getSelection()[0].row;
    let col = 1;
    let valNew = "c";

    //This errors dataTable.setValue is not a function
    dataTable.setValue(row, col, valNew);

    chartWrapper.draw();

  } //END selectHandler_table
} //END example_dashboard(){
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id='div_dashboard'>
  <div id='div_categoryPicker1'></div>
  <div id="div_table"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the error occurs because you are using a DataView to draw the Dashboard,
which is the object returned from the ChartWrapper, and not a DataTable.

you could resolve by passing the DataTable instead,

```
example_dashboard(data);  // use data table here
```

it doesn't appear you are modifying the data using the view.
or if that code just isn't included here,
you can convert the DataView to a DataTable, before drawing the dashboard...

```
example_dashboard(view.toDataTable());  // convert view to DataTable
```

Comment: Most of my code is so deeply layered I can't really post it.   I will take a look at the bits drawing the ChartWrapper table in my codebase and see if I used a DataView .  Thank you for the hint.  I may need further help.  Thank you, I value your assistance!  Your answers always provide clarity.

Comment: I have been able to update front end table with your advice.  However I did not realize I must edit the proxy table, named proxyTable, in the background.  (perhaps it's the only table I have to update?) I don't know how update the proxyTable from the front end table called table_db.  What is the syntax required for me to go to the proxy table from the table_db columns to find and update the matching row.  Date and Product are the unique key columns.  They are named the same in both proxyTable and table_db.